# Is it possible to connect to GCP PostgreSQL via ODBC?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, odbc, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to GCP Postgres. The most convenient method my environment has is an ODBC driver. Will GCP serve that type of connection?

Comment: Can you details from where do you want to connect and what is your current blocker?

Answer (score 1):

That should work.  The server doesn't know it is talking to an ODBC driver. It speaks its native protocol, it is up to the ODBC driver to interpret that.